# Hiding and Showing Edit Input not working(Angular)

Tags: html, angular, typescript, edit, show-hide

I'm trying to make an Edit button, with an input field that appears/disappears when the button is pressed. It was working previously, however when I tried to make a Display form, it doesn't seem to recognize the `"title.value"` This is very strange. I'm using Boolean for an `"edit"` variable combined with a *ngIf to show/hide the form. If I take the `*ngIf="edit"` off, it works normally as a form that displays what you're written. Am I missing something?

Here's the HTML:

```
        <input type="text" #title *ngIf="edit"/>
        <button (click)="edit = !edit">Edit</button>
        <button (click)="getTitle(title.value)">Get Title</button>
        <h2>{{groupTitle}}</h2>
```

and here's the .ts:

```
  public edit = false;
  public groupTitle = "";

  getTitle(val) {
    this.groupTitle = val;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with implementing together the `ngIf` directive and a reference to your input element as `#title`. In that case you can use `hidden` instead of `ngIf`.

Here's your html:

```
<input type="text" #title [hidden]="!edit"/>
<button (click)="edit = !edit">Edit</button>
<button (click)="getTitle(title.value)">Get Title</button>
<h2>{{groupTitle}}</h2>
```

There are couple more elegant ways to bind a value and render it on a page.

The first one is to get rid of the `Get title` button and use `(input)` method directly on an input element.
In that case, Html looks like:

```
<input type="text" #title *ngIf="edit" (input)="getTitle(title.value)"/>
<button (click)="edit = !edit">Edit</button>
<h2>{{groupTitle}}</h2>
```

The second one is to use `[(ngModel])` instead of the `getTitle` method and bind your input value directly to the `groupTitle` variable.

Html will look like:

```
<input type="text" #title *ngIf="edit" [(ngModel)]="groupTitle"/>
<button (click)="edit = !edit">Edit</button>
<h2>{{groupTitle}}</h2>
```

Your .ts file:

```
edit = false;
groupTitle = "";
```

Comment: [hidden] definitely works, thank you. I also implemented the more elegant ways you mentioned that keeps the *ngIf and I'll keep it in mind going forward. It was all experimenting so I can use this function on something else. Again, Thank you very much.